# How to get the all types of updates from linkedin in one request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, request, linkedin-api

I want to fetch the user updates about statuses, shares, connections etc. Linked provide the different update types
https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/network-update-types

There is a need of separate request for each update. how I can get all type of updates in a single request